# Particles system with negative frame start don't work with collider?

Tags: particles, keyframes, collision

I noticed with particles system negative frame start, the particles are not simulated with collider during the negative frames. The bake work, but particles are affected by collider only after frame 0.

I was wondering if there was a solution to this problem ?
Thanks to anyone who has a solution